# Use custom setters or KVO

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing

I researched on this topic for a while.  I'm still not sure is it an good idea to write a custom Setter for a property or is it necessary to use KVO.

What I want to have is as following:

I have a class `MyInputBox` and there're one property called maxCharCount, when the value of maxCharCount is changed, I want to do something.  So to do this, I use:

```
@interface MyInputBox : UITextField
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger maxCharCount;
@end
```

then in the initialize method, I do like this:

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"maxCharCount" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"maxCharCount"]){
        [self setLabelWarningByDefaultText];
    }


}
```

Is it better than using custom Setter?

Besides, if I use custom Setter, when do I need to call 
`willChangeValueForKey:` and `didChangeValueForKey:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your class is a view class, it makes sense that it updates its own view. Therefore, I think it's better to use a custom setter.

KVO is a low level mechanism to get rid of handling your own Observer/Observable pattern. It's useful for other objects to get notifications of changes in an object's properties. I don't see any value of an object observing to its own properties.

If you do implement your custom setters, you don't have to call `willChangeValueForKey:` or `didChangeValueForKey:` yourself. Setting the instance variable is enough

```
- (void)setMaxCount:(NSInteger)count {
    _maxCount = count;
    // Do any updates you want to do
}
```

Answer (score 1):

KVO is fairly slow, and also involves writing a lot of less-than-elegant custom code.

In my opinion, custom setters are cleaner and simpler to write when the custom code you want to trigger is in the class where the property is defined.

KVO is useful when you want to observe a value that changes in another object's property.

I don't think you need to worry about calling willChangeValueForKey and didChangeValueForKey in your custom setter except in unusual circumstances. The system takes care of calling those methods for you when use use property getters and setters.

I suggest reading the chapter "Key-Value Coding programming Guide" in the Xcode documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  When I was coding for Windows Phone with C#, I remembered that customizing setter by myself will cause some strange problems.  So I'm a little bit worried about write setter by myself.  If it's safe to use in iOS side(obj C), I'm ok.

Comment: Why the down-vote? If someone thinks I provided wrong information, by all means speak up!